# error while installing new version of ruby using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm switching my ruby version using RVM

```
rvm install 2.6.3
```

I get this error:

```
Installing required packages: libssl-dev...
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl-dev',
please read /home/bondka/.rvm/log/1562836140_ruby-2.6.3/package_install_libssl-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Comment: Try installing this first - 
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu update your package repository (optional- ignore if already did).

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
```

I hope that helpful.